# Can every continuuous Function be written as a solution to a differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, polynomials

Recently I have been asking myself this question upon the realization that many functions mathematicians work with can be - more or less - defined as the solution to a specific set of differential equations. Here are some known examples:
$$f'=f \rightarrow f=Ce^x$$
$$f'' =f\rightarrow f=C\sinh x$$ or $$f=C\cosh x$$
$$f^{(4)}=f\rightarrow f=C\sin x$$or$$f=C\cos x$$
Since most functions can be represented as sums or products of these functions (including others that I left out in this brief summary, like polynomials), I have been asking myself, whether ivnersely you can find a corresponding differential equation to any arbitrary continuuous function.

Comment: Obviously, a function that is continuous and not differentiable cannot be a solution to an equation that demands its solution to be differentiable.

Comment: Certainly not. Differential equations must have differentiable solutions, if a solution exists. And not all continuous functions are differentiable.

Comment: Thats why I said set of Differential equations. A function may not be differentiable at one point c, however it might be differentiable in the intervals $[-\infty,c)$ and $(c,\infty]$. There isnt any function I can think of that is continuuous and not dífferentiable in every possible interval @Gae.S.

Comment: Most fractal functions have that property, continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere.